# How to fetch a hostname of a remote instance using bash script?

Tags: linux

I want the hostname of a remote serve to use in my script.
I am trying this command in script but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

host= $(ssh -i keylocation ec2-user@ip sudo echo $HOSTNAME)
echo $host
```

It is giving me the following error:
./changeconfig.sh: line 3: hostname(The actual host): command not found

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with you code:

1. The space after the `host=` is significant, so you should remove it.
2. The variable `$HOSTNAME` gets expanded by the local bash.

Try this:

```
host="$(ssh -i keylocation ec2-user@ip echo '$HOSTNAME')"
```

or this

```
host="$(ssh -i keylocation ec2-user@ip hostname)"
```

I remove the `sudo`, usually it is not needed to retrieve the hostname.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciated your quick response. It is working when I am using it as separate command but not working in script. Giving the same error.

Comment: At that time it wasnt allowing me to accept it, now I did.